# How to set the focus to the first input element in an HTML form on IOS?

Tags: ios, forms, input, focus, autofocus

I would like to use my web app with is developed in HTML/PHP on my iPad but I need to have the first input element to be selected in order for my barcode scanner to fill in. 
On other device this is easily done with the autofocus attribute within the input command

I've already tried different browser on IOS or some Javascript (I'm not an expert at it) but didn't manage to make it working.

```
<input type="text" name="scan" autofocus><br>
```

For the moment I have to manually click on the text field in order to select it, each time my page reload, with is unusable.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Check https://medium.com/@brunn/autofocus-in-ios-safari-458215514a5f

Comment: unfortunately it is not a solution to my problem since the filed is not selected